# Import css cdn in sass file and extend class from it

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, scss-lint

I have exposed CSS classes as CDN to be imported into any scss file.
The way i am importing the cdn into my scss file is using
`@import url(cdn_name)`
And in the same file, I have extended one of the classes that is in cdn.
But the issue is that at build time the url is not resolved and it gives error that it could not find the class that is being extended

Is there any way that the url actually gets resolved at build time only so that this error does not come?

Check the following code snippet of scss file

```
@import url("cdn_name");

.abc{
  @extend .def
}
```

The def class is actually there in cdn_name url but is not found at compile time

Comment: try adding link to cdn_name into `index.html`

Comment: I can't use index.html as I am exposing functionality via angular web components
And actually that also leads to build time error